# Centos setting password for user, but still can't log in on it

Tags: centos, centos7, password, login, users

I've got a problem, where even though i set a password and try to log in with it, it doesn't work.
I created a new user called test with password test. When i try to log in i get "access denied".
I tried to re-set the password many times, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you share your logs : /var/loglog/secure

Comment: Do you try to login remote or local ?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Hello, sorry but i'm not on my pc right now.

Answer (score 1):

Use another to check the log by with `sudo tail -f /var/log/secure`
It shows something like this,

```
Jul  4 16:24:06 iz2ze86eplnjdk8exdjimjz sshd[17288]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user lv (1002) tally 31, deny 5
```

From the output it shows the reason, then solve it.

---

For the above case, the user is locked for enter too many uncorrect passwd before.

Check it with `pam_tally2 -u lv`

```
Login           Failures    Latest failure     From
lv                  32      07/04/20 16:24:59  115.171.85.163
```

Reset it with `pam_tally2 -u lvi -r --reset`

```
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
lv                 32    07/04/20 16:24:59  115.171.85.163
```

Check it again `pam_tally2 -u lv`

```
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
lv`                   0
```

After reset on lv, lv can login successful.

Here is the login strategy

`cat /etc/pam.d/sshd`
1  #%PAM-1.0
2  auth required pam_tally2.so deny=5 unlock_time=600 even_deny_root root_unlock_time=60

Answer (score 0):

that's possible when there's no profile file created for user. Please verify under /home there's path for user. If there's none, remove user and when creating account for him use -m option to create home directory it will also consists .profile file.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops the problem was that i hadn't allowed this user in sshd config.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer but adding more detail about what you put in the sshd config to allow the user would make it a better answer for anyone in the future